# gatsby develop returns No native build was found for platform

Tags: node.js, node-modules, gatsby, nvm

I updated all my packages and node versions and now I can't seem to fix this below when I try to run `gatsby develop`

```
verbose set gatsby_log_level: "verbose"
verbose set gatsby_executing_command: "develop"
verbose loading local command from: /Users/XXXXX/Code/site/website/node_modules/gatsby/dist/commands/develop.js
verbose running command: develop

verbose Transition to "initializing"

 ERROR #11903  API.TYPESCRIPT.COMPILATION

There was an unhandled error during compilation for /Users/XXXXX/Code/site/website. Please run the command with the --verbose flag again.
No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=x64 runtime=node abi=111 uv=1 libc=glibc node=19.7.0
    loaded from: /Users/XXXXX/Code/site/website/node_modules/@parcel/watcher




  Error: No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=x64 runtime=node abi=111 uv=1 libc=glibc node=19.7.0
      loaded from: /Users/XXXXX/Code/site/website/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
  
  - node-gyp-build.js:60 Function.load.resolve.load.path
    [el-party-info]/[node-gyp-build]/node-gyp-build.js:60:9
  
  - node-gyp-build.js:22 load
    [el-party-info]/[node-gyp-build]/node-gyp-build.js:22:30
  
  - index.js:1 Object.<anonymous>
    [el-party-info]/[@parcel]/watcher/index.js:1:42
  
  - loader:1275 Module._compile
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14
  
  - loader:1329 Object.Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10
  
  - loader:1133 Module.load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32
  
  - loader:972 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12
  
  - loader:1157 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19
  
  - helpers:119 require
    node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18
  
  - index.js:7 Object.<anonymous>
    [el-party-info]/[@parcel]/fs/lib/index.js:7:28
  
  - loader:1275 Module._compile
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14
  
  - loader:1329 Object.Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10
  
  - loader:1133 Module.load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32
  
  - loader:972 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12
  
  - loader:1157 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19
  
  - helpers:119 require
    node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18
  

not finished compile gatsby files - 0.085s
```

I assume this has to deal with my node version and my macbook.
I'm on Mac 13.0 and I'm using nvm to install and handle what node version I'm using.
But this occurs on node 18 and 19.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason installing gatsby@next fixed it all!